# What does yap<S-}>p do?

Tags: normal-mode

over at https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/8-great-vim-mappings I came across said mapping. While it is clear to me it yanks a paragraph, I'm having trouble decomposing this command. What does the a do there? Why the angled brackets? What is going on?

Answer (score 8):

It's just a poor method of writing it out. In general, anything between `<>` is understood to mean "Not literal keystrokes, but with modifiers". For example, if I was telling someone to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, I would write `<C-a>`.

In this case, `<S-}>` means <kbd>shift</kbd>+`}`, which is a poor way of writing it out since this is the same thing as just `}`, which (from `:help }`) means

```
}           [count] paragraphs forward.  |exclusive| motion.
```

I would have written

```
nnoremap cp yap}p
```

and this would do the exact same thing. You can test this yourself. If you do:

```
nnoremap } <S-}>
```

and hit `}` a couple of times, you can see that it does the same thing.

Comment: On certain keyboards } is not created by using Shift at all. (E.g. [norwegian keyboards where alt gr + 0 is used](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=norwegian+keyboard+setup&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1515&bih=758&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc5abnmtTMAhUEKywKHUqpBXoQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.9#imgrc=qGfs-s1ImjkS7M%3A)). In such a scenario the commands are not identical.